# What Are My args[]?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I've gotten ahead of myself and am taking a semester, which requires that I have knowledge of Java beyond what I've learned. I have no idea how I command like arguments are passed to the main argument, apart from "echo Java foo bar" through the command line
I'm trying to parse JSON through java; I hope that the code below is enough

This is my method:

```
public static void parseCrewWithListMapping(String filePath) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        List<Crew> crews = mapper.readValue(new File(filePath), 
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Crew.class));

        for(Crew crew : crews) {
            System.out.println(crew);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is my main method trying to run this method.

```
public class CrewParsing {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XMLStreamException {

        if(args.length < 1)
             throw new RuntimeException("No argument exception");

        System.out.println("Parsing Crew Names");
        CrewParser.parseCrewWithListMapping(args[2]);
        System.out.println("Finished\n\n");

    }
}
```

All my files are in the correct places, I'm trying to recreate this:

```
public static void parseJSONWithListMapping(String filePath) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        List<Employee> employees = mapper.readValue(new File(filePath), 
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Employee.class));

        for(Employee employee : employees){
            System.out.println(employee);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Method:

```
public static void parseJSONWithListMapping(String filePath) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        List<Employee> employees = mapper.readValue(new File(filePath), 
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Employee.class));

        for(Employee employee : employees){
            System.out.println(employee);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

main method (which worked):

```
public class Practice1Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XMLStreamException {

        if(args.length < 1)
             throw new RuntimeException("No argument exception");

        System.out.println("Parsing Crew Names");
        CrewParser.parseJSONWithListMapping(args[2]);
        System.out.println("Finished\n\n");

    }
}
```

When passing `args[2]` as the arguments for `parseJSONWithListMapping` in the code that worked, I got my json results just fine. 
But when I tried my code, the "no argument exception" was run, which I assume is telling me that there were no arguments passed.

What could be the problem? I really hope that this is enough detail ;_;

Comment: Can you show a sample command line arguments list that you use to run your program?

Comment: args are the arguments you can call the main method with! If you're using eclipse check "Run Configuration" to add some arguments to your launch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your program from the command-line, you may pass in the list of arguments, such as:

```
java CrewParsing jsonPath1 jsonPath2 jsonPath3
```

If you are running from an IDE such as Eclipse, you are probably just clicking the `Run` or `Debug` and forgetting to enter in any arguments. In Eclipse - right-click your main class and when you hover over the `Run(or Debug) as...` choose `run(debug) configuration`. There is a tab for arguments, and you can enter them there. The program you are copying from probably has them set up already.

---

If you want some more information on arguments I find the [Oracle command line tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) explains it well: *(All taken from link)*

> A Java application can accept any number of arguments from the command line. This allows the user to specify configuration information when the application is launched.
>
> The user enters command-line arguments when invoking the application and specifies them after the name of the class to be run. For example, suppose a Java application called Sort sorts lines in a file. To sort the data in a file named friends.txt, a user would enter:

```
java Sort friends.txt
```

> When an application is launched, the runtime system passes the command-line arguments to the application's main method via an array of Strings. In the previous example, the command-line arguments passed to the Sort application in an array that contains a single String: "friends.txt".
>
> The Echo example displays each of its command-line arguments on a line by itself:

```
public class Echo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

> The following example shows how a user might run Echo. User input is in italics.

*java Echo Drink Hot Java*

```
Drink
Hot
Java
//3 separate arguments are all printed out - args[0], args[1], args[2]
```

If you're still not sure what arguments you actually have, I would try printing out your arguments like that tutorial shows you.

Comment: If you are running from an IDE such as Eclipse, you are probably just clicking the Run or Debug and forgetting to enter in any arguments. In Eclipse - right-click your main class and when you hover over the Run(or Debug) as... choose run(debug) configuration. There is a tab for arguments, and you can enter them there. The program you are copying from probably has them set up already. <= oh HAHAHA dang I was NOT even remotely aware of this feature in eclipse. The other things that you have mentioned I knew, but I thought that I was missing something, which actually was no the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're checking `args.length < 1` and throwing the "No argument exception", but then you're trying to use `args[2]`, which is the **third** command-line argument.

If you want the first, it's `args[0]`, the second is `args[1]`, and so on. If you require one argument, your `args.length < 1` is correct and you'd use `args[0]`. If you require two arguments, you'd use `args.length < 2` for the error and then use `args[0]` and `args[1]`.